# Codeigniter 4 - REST with Auto Routing improved

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, url-routing, codeigniter-4

I have a controller App/Controllers/Api/Orders.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controllers\Api;

use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourceController;

class Orders extends ResourceController
{
    protected $modelName = 'App\Models\Order';
    protected $format    = 'json';

    public function getIndex()
    {
        return $this->respond($this->model->findAll());
    }

    public function delete($id = null)
    {
        return $this->respond(['test' => 123]);
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to access `/api/orders/` with GET request it works fine (so auto routing is working).

But when I'm trying to send a DELETE request: `/api/orders/15` I get error 404. What am I doing wrong? The main source of confusion for me is that Codeigniter 4 RESTful documentation seems to talk about manual routes or legacy auto routing but not the improved version where you need to specify `methodFunction` (like `getIndex`).

Running `php spark routes` gives me the following:

```
+--------------+------------------+------+---------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Method       | Route            | Name | Handler                               | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------------+------------------+------+---------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| GET(auto)    | api/orders       |      | \App\Controllers\Api\Orders::getIndex |                | toolbar       |
| DELETE(auto) | api/orders/[/..] |      | \App\Controllers\Api\Orders::delete   | <unknown>      | <unknown>     |
```

CodeIgniter version: 4.3.1

app/Config/Routes.php

```php
$routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\Controllers');
$routes->setDefaultController('Auth');
$routes->setDefaultMethod('index');
$routes->setTranslateURIDashes(false);
$routes->set404Override();
$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');
```

app/Config/Filters.php

```php
public array $globals = [
    'before' => [
        // 'honeypot',
        // 'csrf',
        // 'invalidchars',
    ],
    'after' => [
        'toolbar',
        // 'honeypot',
        // 'secureheaders',
    ],
];
```

Comment: Share your `app/Config/Routes.php` and `app/Config/Filters.php` file contents. In addition, share your exact current CodeIgniter 4 version found in the class's `CI_VERSION` public property of `system/CodeIgniter.php` or `vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/CodeIgniter.php`

Comment: Updated question with requested info

Comment: Just to confirm, what's the value of the `$autoRoutesImproved` property in `app/Config/Feature.php`?

Comment: public bool $autoRoutesImproved = true;

Answer (score 1):

##### Solution:

Beyond prefixing the Controller method with an *HTTP verb* i.e `delete`, you need to provide a *'Controller method name'* as the suffix. I.e: `httpVerbMethodName`.

Instead of: ❌

```php
public function delete($id = null)
{
   // ...
}
```

Use this: ✅

```php
public function deleteOrder($id = null)
{
   // ...
}
```

---

*Route endpoint:*

**DELETE: `http://localhost:4599/api/orders/order/15`**

```bash
| DELETE(auto) | api/orders/order[/..] |      | \App\Controllers\Api\Orders::deleteOrder |                | toolbar
```

---

##### Reference:

[URI Segments](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/routing.html#uri-segments)

> The segments in the URL, in following with the Model-View-Controller approach, usually represent:
>
> ```
> example.com/class/method/ID
> ```
>
> 1. The first segment represents the controller **class** that should be invoked.
> 2. The second segment represents the class **method** that should be called.
> 3. The third, and any additional segments, represent the ID and any variables that will be passed to the controller.
>
> Consider this URI:
>
> ```
> example.com/index.php/helloworld/hello/1
> ```
>
> In the above example, when you send a HTTP request with **GET** method, Auto Routing would attempt to find a controller named `App\Controllers\Helloworld` and executes `getHello()` method with passing `'1'` as the first argument.
>
> **Note**
>
> A controller method that will be executed by Auto Routing (Improved) needs HTTP verb (`get`, `post`, `put`, etc.) prefix like `getIndex()`, `postCreate()`.
>
> See [Auto Routing in Controllers](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/controllers.html#controller-auto-routing-improved) for more info.

Comment: Ok but the RESTful CodeIgniter page lists common (good) practice with RESTful routes like this: `$routes->delete('photos/(:segment)', 'Photos::delete/$1');`. I guess this just means that auto routing doesn't work here

Comment: @user64675 Correct! In that case, you **can't** use auto-routing. Disable Auto-routing by changing `public bool $autoRoutesImproved = false;` in `app/Config/Feature.php` and `$routes->setAutoRoute(false);` in `app/Config/Routes.php`. Then, [manually define routes](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/routing.html#examples) in `app/Config/Routes.php`. I.e: `$routes->delete('api/orders/(:num)', 'Api\Orders::delete/$1');`

Comment: @user64675 Your HTTP request would then be something similar to; `DELETE: http://localhost:4599/api/orders/15`